# Strange Behaviour in Recursive Hierarchy in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, hierarchy

I have come across an interesting problem with a report I am developing for a client using T-SQL and SSRS.

My client requires me to display a hierarchy of entries up to five levels deep, with a report parameter to define the depth of reporting.  The client wants the 5th level to be the lowest level of granularity, the 4th level the level above that, and so on.  The report should show the top level, with the ability to drill down to the lowest level as defined by the report parameter.

The hierarchy is ragged, but the criteria for determining the level of reporting requires a balanced hierarchy.

The following example is given:

```
Level 1                            A
                                   |
                 -----------------------------------------
                |          |              |               |
Level 2         B          C              D               E
                |          |              |               
                |          |          ---------
                |          |         |         |
Level 3         F          G         H         I          -
                |          |                   |
                |          |                   |
                |          |                   |
Level 4         J          K         -         L          -
                |
                |
                |                                          
Level 5         M          -         -          -         -
```

In order to achieve what the client wants, each level below the top level needs to be "pushed down" as far as it will go to create a balanced hierarchy:

```
Level 1                            A
                                   |
                 -----------------------------------------
                |          |               |              |
Level 2         B          X               X              X
                |          |               |              |
                |          |               |              |
                |          |               |              |
Level 3         F          C               D              X
                |          |               |              |
                |          |           ---------          |
                |          |          |         |         |
Level 4         J          G          X         I         X
                |          |          |         |         |
                |          |          |         |         |
                |          |          |         |         |
Level 5         M          K          H         L         E
```

The X's denote imaginary "inserted" nodes.

My report needs to display nodes in the structure of the original hierarchy, but to use the levels on the second diagram above to determine the maximum depth shown.  Therefore, I have not persisted the balanced hierarchy, but simply calculated the new depths for each original node.

I have created a sql table with the hierarchy details:

```
Create Table
    Hierarchy
(
    ID Int,
    Name Varchar(100),
    ParentID Int,
    Ragged_Hierarchy_Depth Int,
    Balanced_Hierarchy_Depth Int
);

Insert Into
    Hierarchy
(
    ID,
    Name,
    ParentID,
    Ragged_Hierarchy_Depth,
    Balanced_Hierarchy_Depth
)
Values
    (   1, 'A', Null, 1, 1  ),
    (   2, 'B', 1, 2, 2 ),
    (   3, 'C', 1, 2, 3 ),
    (   4, 'D', 1, 2, 3 ),
    (   5, 'E', 1, 2, 5 ),
    (   6, 'F', 2, 3, 3 ),
    (   7, 'G', 3, 3, 4 ),
    (   8, 'H', 4, 3, 5 ),
    (   9, 'I', 4, 3, 4 ),
    (   10, 'J', 6, 4, 4    ),
    (   11, 'K', 7, 4, 5    ),
    (   12, 'L', 9, 4, 5    ),
    (   13, 'M', 10, 5, 5   );
```

To demonstrate the problem, I have created a report with the two hierarchy groups and a Hierarchy_Level integer parameter:

[image: SSRS Design View]

I have implemented recursive grouping on the ParentID in each group.  For each group, I have used the following expressions for filtering:

Ragged_Hierarchy    :   Ragged_Hierarchy_Depth.Value <= Parameters!Hierarchy_Level.Value
Balanced_Hierarchy  :   Balanced_Hierarchy_Depth.Value <= Parameters!Hierarchy_Level.Value

The visibility of each group is set to be hidden if (Level()>0) and is toggled by the first textbox in the row.

[image: SSRS Report]

The Ragged_Hierarchy group displays correctly, hiding the levels below the selected level.  In the Balance_Hierarchy group, however, there are expand/collapse icons for levels 2-4 when there is nothing to show beneath them.  They do not drilldown into anything when expanded, but I cannot seem to get rid of them.  When I export the report to Excel, the unwanted icons disappear - it is only in the online report that they show.

Is there a way to prevent these icons from appearing, without resorting to a costly workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now resolved this problem.  The filter applied to the Balanced_Hierarchy group also needs to be applied to the recursive parent expression.

So instead of:

```
=Fields!ParentID.Value
```

The expression should be:

```
=IIf(
    (Fields!Balanced_Hierarchy_Depth.Value <= Parameters!Hierarchy_Level.Value),
    Fields!ParentID.Value,
    Nothing
)
```

It would appear that SSRS recursive groupings apply group filters *after* determining the parent-child relationships.  Therefore the filter needs to be applied at the time the parent-child relationship is determined.